# What is an efficient way to calculate the KL divergence between two kernel densities

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel-density

I am trying to calculate the approximate KL divergence of two probabity distributions X and Y from samples drawn from each of them. To do this, it seemed reasonable to first approximate the probability distributions by using Kernel density estimations:

```
data_kde       = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth="scott").fit(data)
prediction_kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth="scott").fit(pred)
```

But how can I efficiently calculate the KL divergence of the resulting densities?

The only thing I came up with was feeding a linspace of the sample space and take the exponential of the log-likelyhood of these points. The resulting probabilities I could feed into the KL divergence.

Answer (score 0):

One can use kernel density approximation and solve the integral that is the KL divergence numerically. Quite slow though.

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Generate two random probability distributions
p = np.random.rand(samples)
q = np.random.rand(samples)

# Estimate the kernel density of the samples
kernel_p = gaussian_kde(p)
kernel_q = gaussian_kde(q)

inter = max(p) - min(p)
start = min(p) - inter/2
stop  = max(p) + inter/2

# Evaluate the KL divergence
kl_div, _ = quad(lambda x: (kernel_p(x) * np.log2(kernel_p(x) / kernel_q(x))), start, stop)
```